# Can we set the value for Remember of flash player Allow Deny dialog from Actionscript code?

Tags: actionscript-3, camera, flash-player-11

I am recording user's video through actionscript code.i am attaching camera from two different swf files.So the problem with that is the user faces the dialog box twice which i dont want.Also i know the remember checkbox functionality which i want to set true from my action script code without requiring the user to check the remember checkbox.So pls help is there any way to set the value true for remember checkbox from my action script code?

Answer (score 0):

No. That is not possible to do (changing a client-side security setting via downloaded code is an extremely bad thing) and is explicitly not permitted.

You will have to either merge your SWF files or live with the dialog.

Comment: i didnt understand your solution? live with the dialog??

Comment: The solution is to merge the SWF files: if you can't merge them then you have no option but to accept the dialog (which is what I meant by *live with the dialog*). There is no API, documented or otherwise, that will allow you to write code that changes a user's permissions settings.